# intervention-image with laravel 5.2 on ubuntu-server breaks the other calls

Tags: laravel, intervention

I am using laravel 5.2 to write services for a mobile app. all the calls are working fine. My project is deployed in ubuntu server.

Now I want to resize the uploaded images inorder to maintain same performance. I thought of trying intervention-image.

In local machine it worked fine. I installed intervention-image and set the provider and alias name, I included the alias name to controller. Once I do that and update the server, all the other calls are getting effected. I am getting 505 error.

It's the intervension-image which is causing this problem, I checked with previous upload and I am getting all the calls. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a dev environment like your production , use vagrant . About error 505 check you error log file to have more detail about the bug

Comment: I may sound rude but your answer was not helpful at all. I already tried that and the code is working fine untill I use intervension. I cross-checked the set up as well but there is nothing wrong. Somehow the calls are breaking or not responding as before.

Comment: Sorry  i was trying to help ,are you sure to use the same php version in both env et same composer.json file?

Comment: Could you please explain more about " Are you sure to use same php version in both env et same composer.json file?" I couldn't understand. Are you asking about the version of .php in local and server?

Comment: intervention-image neede a least php 5.4 . Each local server and live server has configuration of php and mysql .First Make sure you are using the same php version by runing php --version or using phpinfo() .   About composer.json  all package are declared there so if you deploying live without updating this file in your live server can make issue in your program, that why when you call alias name ,you have error cause library dont exist

Comment: Okay, I got that. there is no issues with the php version. and I added the providers and alias as required. composer.json file is fine aswell. Locally using a blade file I was able to upload and resize the file though there was some issue with very large files. But within 400mb it handled it smoothly. However, I am writing a service call for ionic2 project. there I am facing the problem. its breaking ther rest of the calls which infact was working before including intervension/image.